# How to Resize gvis chart by drag and drop- by on the fly

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, ggvis

Is there a way to resize gvis chart using mouse drag and drop - on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

In your chart's `options` list, add `explorer: { actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'] }`

Look at Configuration options (for the bar chart for example) in the Google Charts documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#configuration-options).